# Notepad++ hotkey to `mark all` search text

Tags: notepad++, hotkeys

What is the shortcut to mark all the text in search box?

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has nothing to do with the purpose of this site.

Comment: Control - A? Select All?

Comment: @tombull89 You get me wrong :(

Comment: @Xavierjazz Notepad++ is a brilliant alternative for the built-in notepad and free and clean of virus. This site is about how to use computer right? And I doubt it if you use the PC and hardly work with text editor

Answer (score 1):

I was missing this feature, too, and I **solved it**.

---

### Your red circle 1 (open dialog at Mark tab):

Create an [AutoHotKey](http://autohotkey.com) macro, which converts custom shortcut
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> into keystrokes

```
^+M::Send ^+f+{Tab}{Right}  ;sends Ctrl+Shift+F, Shift+Tab, right arrow :)
```

I recommend using this macro in proper context as shown in [this
answer](https://superuser.com/a/816894/287473).

**Note:** be sure you are using new Notepad++. In old versions, tabs can't be switched by keystrokes.

---

### Your red circle 3 (press button by keyboard accelerator):

1. At your Notepad++ folder, find file `english_customizable.xml`
2. Open the file for editing
3. Find line `<Item id="1615" name="Find All"/>`
4. Put `&amp;` before letter you want to see underlined.
   Example: to create underlined `A` use: `<Item id="1615" name="Find &amp;All"/>`
   (**Tip:** add any other accelerators you wish. Works everywhere except the tabs.)
5. Save the file
6. In *Preferences* window, change language to `English (customizable)`
   If you already were using this language, swich to another one and switch back.
7. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

It is the default button so pressing [Enter] will Mark All. That very faint blue fringe around the button is the visual indication of which button is the default and is the action performed when Enter is pressed.

The blue is more noticeable in the Windows 7 Aero theme vs what looks like Windows 8 in your screen capture.

[image]

Comment: How to open the box via hotkey @Brian? That would be quicker way I'm looking for. Ctrl-F and switching the tab is quite tiring to me.

Comment: @NamG.VU – opening **Mark** box via hotkey is currently not implemented, I know something about that. Regarding **Mark All** button – you should be able to add accelerator by your self by modifying your language file. If selected langugage is English, switch it to `English (Customizable)` before.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question to mean that you want to highlight (mark) a keyword (wherever it occurs in the text) in response to a keyboard shortcut. Given that Notepad++ removes the markings when a file is reloaded, having a keyboard shortcut avoids a long-winded procedure, especially when multiple keywords need marking.

Notepad++ for a long time has had macro recording built in, and it does the job nicely:

1. List item
2. Select the menu-item Macro->Start Recording
3. Type the text to be marked in the text
4. Press "Mark All"
5. Option: repeat steps 2 and 3 for all keywords that need marking
6. Select the menu-item Macro->Stop Recording

Now every time the file is reloaded, just press Ctrl+Shift+P to run the macro and all keywords will be marked instantly.