# Create a shortcut for Notepad++ to reopen a closed tab?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, macros, tabs

To reopen a closed tab in Notepad++ you press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>&<kbd>1</kbd>. I was wondering if there was a way to make a macro or program to do this so that I can press link it to the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> instead, which is a universal reopen closed tab shortcut I'm used to.

If anyone could tell me how to make a simple program that does that, and that I could then link to Notepad++ to create a shortcut with, that would teach me a lot and help.

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully tested the following solution: define this [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org) macro:

```
SendMode Input                ;just to set up preferred method of sending hotkeys
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx      ;from now on, windows titles are matched by regex

#IfWinActive Notepad\+\+      ;(open block) the following hotkeys work only in N++
+^t::Send !f1                 ;desired hotkey: Ctrl+Shift+T sends Alt+F, 1
^w::Send ^{F4}                ;bonus: Ctrl+W sends Ctrl+F4 (close file convention)
#IfWinActive                  ;(close #IfWinActive block)
```

do not forget to run AutoHotKey as administrator.

Using the AHK you can achieve many useful things in N++ and all other applications.

Comment: I am incredibly grateful. Thank you so much @miroxlav.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is already the default for reopen closed tabs.

You can always use the ShortCut Mapper :
[image]

[image]